# How to redirect WebBrowser control of another Application

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, plugins, activex, web-controls

I have Application, and I can't modify it. This Application contain IEControl (WebBrowser control), which display some URLs and open some txt files. How can I get IWebBrowser2 and redirect this control to specified URL? For example, I need redirect this control to `http://stackoverflow.com` every time control trying to open txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without serious hacks that would be unsupported and rather fragile.  You'd have to inject your code across the process boundary using any of a number of tricks, none of which are trivial.

Why would you want to do this?